# Asynchronous Function in Iteration - javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, d3.js

I am trying not to replicate code and loop over a a function in d3 that is asynchronous. Here is some code

Since d3.text is asynchronous , I am not able to use the index `u` in a correct way to append objects to the DOM. How should I go about this? I need the loop to go to next iteration once d3.text finished

```
for(var u in urls) {
  console.log(u);
  var url = "interest_points/" + urls[u] + ".csv";
  var data_gpBy_month = {};
  var sortable_month = []

  d3.text(url, function(text) {
    // some code...
    var data = d3.csv.parseRows(text).map(function(row) {
      //some code...        
    });

    //some code
  });           
}
```

Comment: Why not capture the value of u within the anonymous function, then pass the captured value as a parameter to the inner function? That is, capture the index var at the outer closure and pass it cleanly to the inner closure?

Comment: Yes, it sounds like what @DavidW suggest is the right approach (unlike any of the answers below), assuming that the problem is that by the time the callback is executed, `u` gets set to the its value from the very last loop iteration.

Comment: My Javascript skills are limited so if you show me how to do that , I would really appreciate it. @meetamit yes that is what is happening

Comment: Hi @Saher I've seen some answers that basically illustrated what I suggested about capturing the value, but your note that "you want to go to next iteration once d3.text finishes" This concerns me a bit. If d3.text is async, then the code isn't going to block on the call, but it sounds like you're *wanting* it to block on the call. Do you have to guarantee execution order of the .Text calls?

Comment: yes the first answer solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EYAYT/2/) ?

```
var urls = ["asd", "asdasd", "Asdasfa"];
var currentUrlIndex = 0;
var getUrl = function(){
    if (currentUrlIndex >= urls.length){
        return null;
    } else {
      return "interest_points/" + urls[currentUrlIndex++] + ".csv";
    }
}

var execd3Text = function(){
    var url = getUrl();
    if (url){
        d3.text(url, function(text) {                                               

                  //some code;;
                  execd3Text();
                });
    }
}

execd3Text();
```

Comment: you might want to fix the indexing. This will start from 1

Comment: No, it works, check the fiddle. currentUrlIndex++ first returns, and then increments.

Comment: not sure because I had to change it to work it was starting from first index... Thanks for the answer though!

Answer (score 1):

The loop should simply become this:

```
for(var u in urls) { loadParseAndRender(u); }
```

All your existing logic then moves into `loadParseAndRender`, but at this point `u` will never get overridden. I.e, in fancy terms, it gets captured in the closure.

```
function loadParseAndRender(u) {
  // the rest of your code
}
```

What David W suggested is the same thing as abive, but without creating a named function for it, you'd do this:

```
for(var _u in urls) {
  (function(u) { // this is an anonymous function
    // the rest of you code
  })(_u) // this function gets called as soon as it's declared 
}
```

Comment: Hey meetamit, this is nice, but the op mentioned that he needs the loop to go to the next iteration once the previous iteration is completed. If I understand correctly, doing it like this, with a function call, does not guarantee the callback execution order. It will depend on how fast the ajax returns.

Comment: @pax162 That's true... the order is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood properly:

```
function doSomething(array) {
  var u = array.shift();
  console.log(u);

  var url = "interest_points/" + urls[u] + ".csv";
  var data_gpBy_month = {};
  var sortable_month = []

  d3.text(url, function(text) {
    // some code...
    var data = d3.csv.parseRows(text).map(function(row) {
    //some code...        
    });

    //some code

    if (array.length > 0)
      doSomething(array); 
 });           


 doSomething(Object.keys(urls));
```